# What is the purpose of Alt-F4?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I used to close a running application by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. But, I realised that the application is still running and the correct way to close (quit) it is the combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> keys.

So, what is the purpose of <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and how is it different from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> send a close message to the window, as when you press the little x button on the title bar. It is a windows manager configuration.

It depends upon the application whether to respond to this event closing all together the application, or iconize (i.e. like xchat can be configured) or other.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> shortcut you mention is not universal, every application can have its own. For example `evince` use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, some other use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> to close, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> to close a single tab and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> to close all tabs (but not all windows).

Comment: what i have observed is that Alt-F4 saves the unsaved documents and then terminates

Answer (score 13):

This entirely depends on the application.

By default, applications bind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> such that it does the same as *closing the window*. For some applications that means quitting (like the Calculator), for others it might mean putting them in the background (like Empathy).

The job of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is the developers' free choice, but convention dictates that it **q**uits the application.

In short: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> will normally do the same thing as clicking [image: the X window button]. If that only hides the windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> will normally quit the application.

Comment: Not 'If that only hides the windows,' it's 'closes the windows,'.

Comment: @Oxwivi What do you mean by 'closes the window'? If it doesn't quit the application, then how is it different from 'hides the window'?

Comment: @db42, if you say hide the window, it gives the impression that the window is hidden with it's content intact. You don't close a Firefox window which returns to how it was before when you open a new window does it?

Comment: `hiding` means `minimize`;so leaving it running where you use the window buttons on the panel to get it back; closing also removes it from the panel. (note: technically Unity has no panel anymore ;) )

Comment: When a window is hidden, it's technically destroyed. Such as when you click the [x] on empathy. But the application (what's called the 'main loop' in gtk) is still running. Clicking the Empathy icon in the messaging menu re-creates the window.

Comment: @Stefano: Application authors do not need to bind Alt+F4 any more than they need to create the "X" button on the chrome. They are the same mechanism. The window manager provides that by default, and requests the window be deleted. The application can prevent window deletion/destruction, but cannot prevent the window manager from merely sending the request.

Comment: @Joe indeed, quite a blunder :-) It's corrected now