# Close window shortcuts command on XFCE

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce

I want to remap the "close window" shortcut on my xubuntu. The original shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

However, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is not listed in my keyboard shortcut lists.(Although I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close windows on my computer). I can't find the exact command to run "close window" process.

[image: screenshot]

I am wondering what is the command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> corresponds to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
xfce4-settings-manager
```

Tab window manager--> keyboard[image: Shortcut.png]

Comment: Thanks! I used "keyboard->Application shortcuts" instead of "window manager -> keyboard". The second one works for me.

Comment: Thank you! That is essential information for users of reduced keyboards without function keys; see https://68keys.io

Comment: Many applications adhere to [the convention of quitting the application with `Ctrl`+`Q`](https://askubuntu.com/a/46921/164341), but not all do. Assigning this key stroke to `Close window` brings some uniformity, even though closing a window is not always equivalent to quitting an application.